# custom word count using hadoop

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

I'm a beginer in hadoop. 
I've understood the WordCount program. Now I have a problem. I dont want the output of all the words..

`- Words_I_Want.txt -

hello

echo

raj`

`- Text.txt -

hello eveyone. I want hello and echo  count`

---

output should be
`hello 2

 echo  1

 raj   0`

---

Now that was an exaple, My actual data is **very** large.

Answer (score 2):

In the [WordCount example](http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/WordCount), the `Mapper` outputs each tokenized word from the input value and the number 1:

```
while (tokenizer.hasMoreTokens()) {
    word.set(tokenizer.nextToken());
    output.collect(word, one);
}
```

If you only want to count certain words, then wouldn't you want to only output words from your `Mapper` that are matches against your list?

```
while (tokenizer.hasMoreTokens()) {
    String token = tokenizer.nextToken();
    if (wordsThatYouCareAbout.contains(token)) {
        word.set(token);
        output.collect(word, one);
    }
}
```

Comment: my data is too big to consider it as a `String wordsThatYouCareAbout;`

Comment: Sorry for not making it clear but I was assuming that you would use some sort of `Set` or `Collection`, not a string. How large is the data?

Comment: As long as you can fit file `Words_I_Want.txt` in RAM this can run smoothly.

Comment: So in every `map()` function i've to load this set of words from `Words_I_Want.txt` (assuming i can fit it into the memory) and  check for `if (wordsThatYouCareAbout.contains(token))` ? This idea looks bad for the reason ** I've to read the Words_I_Want.txt every time in the the `map()` function **

Answer (score 0):

matt b's answer is definitely good for large to small joins but let's assume you're doing a large to large join.

You can map Words_I_Want.txt:
k: the word, v: some marker

You can then map Text.txt:
k: the word, v: 1 (same as the standard word count)

You'll have to use [MultipleInputs](http://hadoop.apache.org/common/docs/r0.19.0/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapred/lib/MultipleInputs.html) and figure out which file is which using  conf.get("map.input.file").

Then in the reduce step you can only collect output when the key has a marker.